# Execute saved queries in table SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the list of select statements:

```
 query
 ----------------------------
 Select Max(acc),Min(acc)  from my_table1
 Select Max(acc),Min(acc)  from my_table2
 Select Max(acc),Min(acc)  from my_table3
 .......
```

I want to execute all saved queries in the table and save the all result in a new table. because all the result should matches(MAX and MIN).

Comment: You want to excute statments, or save the results of those statments in another table?

Comment: Execute queries as string, take result out as xml auto, and save in db. If you know all your queries have same fields, write straight INSERT INTO query with SELECT.

Comment: @Sami I want to execute the queries and save the result in a new table

Comment: you can use cursor and append INSERT INTO query to per row query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cursor over your table and execute as dynamic t-sql adding `insert into` at the beginning of every value with SQL statement.

```
CREATE TABLE tSELECT 
(
    query VARCHAR(1000)
);
INSERT INTO tselect VALUES ('Select Max(acc),Min(acc)  from my_table1')
CREATE TABLE result (min INT, max int);

BEGIN
    DECLARE @stmt VARCHAR(1000);
    DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  SELECT * FROM tselect;
    OPEN db_cursor  FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @stmt
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
    BEGIN   
           EXEC('insert into result ' + @stmt);

           FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @stmt   
    END   

    CLOSE db_cursor   
    DEALLOCATE db_cursor    
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `UNION ALL` like this:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

select 
    @sql = case when @sql is null then '' else @sql + ' union all ' end + query
from 
    t;

insert into destinationTable (max, min)
EXEC sp_executesql (@sql);
```

Comment: really nice one